# How to code if-statement with short-circuit

Tags: javascript, if-statement, short-circuiting

I am new to JavasSript and an trying to code an `if` statement with short-circuiting.

In the code below, the first one is trying to see if the input is 1, show on a console page, 'yes', otherwise, 'no'.

```
function checking (input) {
    ((input==1 && return 'yes') || return 'no')
}
```

However, for some reason, I could see both, 'yes' and 'no', when input is 1. I tried testing by replacing `return` with `console.log`:

```js
checking(1); 
function checking (input) {
    ((input==1 && console.log('yes')) || console.log('no'))
}
// output => yes 
// output => no
```

Then, I figured out that `console.log('yes')` is returning 'undefined'.

How can I fix this?

And how can I replace `console.log()` with `return`? The earlier code with return is producing a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

`console.log` returns `undefined`, which is falsey, so

```
((input==1 && console.log('yes')) || console.log('no'))
// equivalent to:
((true && console.log('yes')) || console.log('no'))
((true && undefined         ) || console.log('no'))
((        undefined         ) || console.log('no'))
```

So the second `console.log` runs as well, because the part in the first parentheses evaluates to a falsey expression.

I suppose you could change the logic so that the `console.log` part is part of another expression that evaluates to `true`:

```js
checking(1); 
function checking (input) {
    ((input==1 && (console.log('yes')) || true) || console.log('no'))
}
```

But this is really, really weird to do, use the conditional operator instead:

```js
checking(1); 
function checking (input) {
  console.log(
    input === 1
    ? 'yes'
    : 'no'
  );
}
```

Or `if`/`else`, if you need multiple statements rather than a single expression based on the condition:

```js
checking(1); 
function checking (input) {
  if (input === 1) {
    console.log('yes');
    // do something depending on input 1
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which is used like this:

```
function checking(input) {

  return input === 1 ? "yes" : "no";

}
```

If `value` is `1` then it will return `"yes"`, if not `"no"` is returned.

I hope my answer helped a bit.